# Photoelectric Effect - Effect of light intensity and frequency on current saturation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, photons, photoelectric-effect

My book gives a question that what'll happen when both the frequency and intensity of a light source is doubled? I think that current saturation should increase on increasing intensity of light because more electrons are now coming out due to the fact that more photons are now hitting the metal surface. In addition, I think that the energy of photoelectrons will not get doubled up. I deduce this from the relation, $K_{max} = h\nu - W$, where $K_{max}$ is maximum kinetic energy of the photoelectrons, $h$ is the universal Planck's constant, $\nu$ is the frequency of the incident light and $W$ is the work function of the metal surface.

Now, according to the answer given in my book, the saturation current remains almost constant on doubling up both frequency and the intensity of the light source. I couldn't understand this.